# How to memcpy without operation IAR compiler

Tags: c, memcpy

I want to memcpy.

```
struct pbuf {
    struct pbuf *next;
    void *payload;
    u16_t tot_len;
    u16_t len;
    u8_t /*pbuf_type*/ type;
    u8_t flags;
    u16_t ref;
};

uint8_t *buffer;
struct pbuf *q;
memcpy( (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)q->payload + payloadoffset), (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)buffer + bufferoffset),     byteslefttocopy);
```

I want to do memcpy without using an operator on a pointer

so i edit like this

```
memcpy( (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)&q->payload[payloadoffset]), (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)&buffer[bufferoffset]),     byteslefttocopy);
```

The compiler spits out this error

expression must be a pointer to a complete object type.

How should I change it?

Comment: what do you mean by "without using operator on a pointer"? `&`, `()` (cast) and `->` are all operators that operate on pointers

Comment: @phuclv and also `[]` lol.

Comment: `&((uint8_t*)q->payload)[payloadoffset]`?